# PIC18F25K50, ADS1114 and I2C

Tags: pic, adc, i2c, ads

I have a minor problem here. I am programming a board with PIC18F25K50 on which I also have three ADCs (ADS1114 from Texas Instruments) for three loadcells. It is a HID device, I have the USB part ready and functional (I'm using this library https://github.com/signal11/m-stack), but I have a problem with I2C (or at least I think the problem is here). I!m using the I2C library from Pololu of their P-Star (that device has the same chip, ie P18F25K50), the code for the library is including my main.c code, below.

```
/------------
--- i2c.c ---
// Copyright Pololu Corporation.  For more information, see https://www.pololu.com/
 
// This is a library for using the PIC18F25K50's Master Synchronous
// Serial Port (MSSP) in I2C Master mode to communicate with I2C
// devices.  See i2c.h for documentation.
 
// TODO: allow setting the speed
 
#include "i2c.h"
#include "system.h"
#include <xc.h>
 
void i2cInit()
{
    // Set up the SCL and SDA pins as pulled-up inputs.
#if defined(__18F25K50) || defined(__18F45K50)
    // Note: This could have a side effect of enabling pull-ups on other pins on
    // Port B.  If you want to avoid that, set the WPUB register to 0 before
    // calling this.
    ANSB0 = 0;
    ANSB1 = 0;
    WPUB0 = 1;
    WPUB1 = 1;
    RBPU = 0;
#endif
 
    // SMP = 0: Slew rate control enabled.
    // CKE = 1: Enable input logic so that thresholds are compliant with SMBus.
    //   Looks like this means the input high voltage will be 2.1 V instead
    //   of 0.7 VDD = 3.5 V, so that's nice.  Also makes the input low voltage
    //   be 0.8 V instead of 0.3 VDD, according to the PIC18F25K50 datasheet.
    // The other 6 bits are read-only.
    SSP1STAT = 0b01000000;
 
    // Reset other MSSP registers to their default values.
    SSP1CON2 = 0;
    SSP1CON3 = 0;
 
    // Set the I2C frequency to 100 kHz.
#if _XTAL_FREQ == 48000000
    SSP1ADD = 119;
#else
#error Not sure how to handle this _XTAL_FREQ.
#endif
 
    // Set up I2C master mode, with clock = FOSC / 4 / (SSP1ADD+1).
    SSP1CON1 = 0b00101000;
}
 
// Generates an I2C Start condition.  This function can fail if there is a bus
// collision (see I2C_COLLISION()).
static void i2cStart()
{
    BCLIF = 0;
    SEN = 1;
    while (SEN);
}
 
// Generates an I2C Repeated Start condition.  This function could cause an
// infinite loop if there is something forcing the SCL line high or low.
// This function can fail if there is a bus collision (see I2C_COLLISION()).
static void i2cRepeatedStart()
{
    RSEN = 1;
    while (RSEN);
}
 
// Generates an I2C Stop condition.  This function could cause an infinite loop
// if there is something forcing the SDA line high or low.
void i2cStop()
{
    PEN = 1;
    while (PEN);
}
 
// Writes a byte to the I2C slave.  Use I2C_ACKED() if you want to know whether
// the slave acknowledged the byte or not.  This function could cause an
// infinite loop if there is something forcing the SCL line low.  This function
// can fail if there is a bus collision (see I2C_COLLISION()).
void i2cWriteByte(uint8_t b)
{
    SSPIF = 0;
    SSP1BUF = b;
    while (!SSPIF);
}
 
// Reads a byte from the I2C slave.  If the ack argument is 0, it does not
// acknowledge the byte (meaning this is the last byte to be read).  If the ack
// argument is 1, it acknowledges the byte.  This function could cause an
// infinite loop if there is something forcing the SCL line low.
uint8_t i2cReadByte(uint8_t ack)
{
    SSPIF = 0;
    RCEN = 1;
    while (!SSPIF);
    uint8_t r = SSP1BUF;
    ACKDT = !ack;
    ACKEN = 1;
    while (ACKEN);
    return r;
}
 
// Returns 1 if there was an I2C bus collision and 0 if there was not.
#define I2C_COLLISION() (BCLIF)
 
// This is meant to be called after i2cWriteByte and it returns 1 if
// an acknowledgment was received from the slave for the byte written.
#define I2C_ACKED() (!ACKSTAT)
 
uint8_t i2cPerformTransfers(const I2CTransfer * transfer)
{
    i2cStart();
    if (I2C_COLLISION())
    {
        return 1;
    }
 
    uint8_t n = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        if (transfer->flags & I2C_FLAG_READ)
        {
            i2cWriteByte((transfer->address << 1) | 1);
            if (!I2C_ACKED())
            {
                i2cStop();
                return 4 + (n * 4) + 1;
            }
 
            for (uint8_t i = 0; i < transfer->length; i++)
            {
                uint8_t ack = i < transfer->length - 1;
                transfer->buffer[i] = i2cReadByte(ack);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i2cWriteByte(transfer->address << 1);
            if (!I2C_ACKED())
            {
                i2cStop();
                return 4 + (n * 4) + 1;
            }
 
            for (uint8_t i = 0; i < transfer->length; i++)
            {
                i2cWriteByte(transfer->buffer[i]);
                if (!I2C_ACKED())
                {
                    i2cStop();
                    return 4 + (n * 4) + 2;
                }
            }
        }
 
        if (transfer->flags & I2C_FLAG_STOP) { break; }
        transfer++;
        n++;
 
        i2cRepeatedStart();
 
        if (I2C_COLLISION())
        {
            return 4 + (n * 4);
        }
    }
 
    i2cStop();
    return 0;
}
 
 
 
 
/------------
--- i2c.h ---
// Copyright Pololu Corporation.  For more information, see https://www.pololu.com/
 
// This is the header file for i2c.c, a library for using the PIC18F25K50's
// Master Synchronous Serial Port (MSSP) in I2C Master mode to communicate with
// I2C devices.
 
#ifndef _I2C_H
#define _I2C_H
 
#include <stdint.h>
 
// This should be called at the beginning of the program.
void i2cInit(void);
 
// This struct represents a one-way transfer of data to or from an I2C device.
typedef struct I2CTransfer {
  uint8_t address;
  uint8_t flags;
  uint8_t * buffer;
  uint8_t length;
} I2CTransfer;
 
// The flags field should be a bitwise combination of a subset of these flags:
#define I2C_FLAG_READ  0x01
#define I2C_FLAG_STOP  0x02
 
// Performs a series of transfers to I2C devices.
//
// The argument should point to an array of transfers where the last transfer is
// indicated with I2C_FLAG_STOP in its flags field.
//
// The return value will be one of these:
// - 0: success
// - 1:  Error occurred on the first start.
// - 4 + N*4 + 0: Error with transfer N: Repeated start for transfer failed.
// - 4 + N*4 + 1: Error with transfer N: Device did not ACK its address.
// - 4 + N*4 + 2: Error with transfer N: Device did not ACK data written.
//
// Because of the way errors are encoded, you should not do more than
// 63 transfers with this function.
//
// If there are multiple transfers, this function uses I2C
// repeated starts between the transfers.  This function could cause an
// infinite loop if there is something wrong with the I2C bus or the devices on it.
uint8_t i2cPerformTransfers(const I2CTransfer * transfers);
 
#endif
 
 
 
 
/-------------
--- main.c ---
#define _XTAL_FREQ 48000000
 
#include <xc.h>
#include <string.h>
    
#include "usb/usb.h"
#include "usb/usb_config.h"
#include "usb/usb_ch9.h"
#include "usb/usb_hid.h"
    
#include "i2c.h"
 
#include "hardware.h"
 
uint16_t readLoadcell(uint8_t devAddr) {
    uint8_t buff[4];
    
    buff[0] = 0x01; // Select config register
    buff[1] = 0b00000100; // Config register
    buff[2] = 0b10000011; // Config register
    buff[3] = 0x00; //Select conversion register
   
    uint8_t valueBuff[2];
    
    I2CTransfer transfersConf[2];
 
    //Write to config register
    transfersConf[0].address = devAddr;
    transfersConf[0].flags = 0;
    transfersConf[0].buffer = &buff;
    transfersConf[0].length = 4;
 
    //Read from conversion register
    transfersConf[1].address = devAddr;
    transfersConf[1].flags = I2C_FLAG_READ | I2C_FLAG_STOP;
    transfersConf[1].buffer = &valueBuff;
    transfersConf[1].length = 2; // I'm reading two bytes (16bit conversion result)
    
    i2cPerformTransfers(transfersConf);
    
    return ((uint16_t)valueBuff[0] << 8) | valueBuff[1];
}
 
int main(void) {
    hardware_init();
    
    i2cInit();
    usb_init(); 
    
    uint8_t RxAxisAddr = 0b1001000;       
    uint8_t RyAxisAddr = 0b1001001;     
    uint8_t RzAxisAddr = 0b1001011;
     
    while(1) { 
        uint16_t *buf = usb_get_in_buffer(1);
        buf[0] = readLoadcell(RxAxisAddr); // Rx Axis
        buf[1] = 10000; // Ry Axis
        buf[2] = 0; // Rz Axis     
 
        usb_send_in_buffer(1, 6);
        __delay_ms(100); //Delay
      
        /*#ifndef USB_USE_INTERRUPTS
            usb_service();
        #endif*/
    }
   
    return 0;
}
 
/* Callbacks. These function names are set in usb_config.h. */
void app_set_configuration_callback(uint8_t configuration) {
 
}
 
uint16_t app_get_device_status_callback() {
    return 0x0000;
}
 
void app_endpoint_halt_callback(uint8_t endpoint, bool halted) {
 
}
 
int8_t app_set_interface_callback(uint8_t interface, uint8_t alt_setting) {
    return 0;
}
 
int8_t app_get_interface_callback(uint8_t interface) {
    return 0;
}
 
void app_out_transaction_callback(uint8_t endpoint) {
 
}
 
void app_in_transaction_complete_callback(uint8_t endpoint) {
 
}
 
int8_t app_unknown_setup_request_callback(const struct setup_packet *setup) {
    /* To use the HID device class, have a handler for unknown setup
     * requests and call process_hid_setup_request() (as shown here),
     * which will check if the setup request is HID-related, and will
     * call the HID application callbacks defined in usb_hid.h. For
     * composite devices containing other device classes, make sure
     * MULTI_CLASS_DEVICE is defined in usb_config.h and call all
     * appropriate device class setup request functions here.
     */
    return process_hid_setup_request(setup);
}
 
int16_t app_unknown_get_descriptor_callback(const struct setup_packet *pkt, const void **descriptor) {
    return -1;
}
 
void app_start_of_frame_callback(void) {
 
}
 
void app_usb_reset_callback(void) {
 
}
 
/* HID Callbacks. See usb_hid.h for documentation. */
 
static uint8_t report_buf[3];
 
static int8_t get_report_callback(bool transfer_ok, void *context) {
    /* Nothing to do here really. It either succeeded or failed. If it
     * failed, the host will ask for it again. It's nice to be on the
     * device side in USB. */
    return 0;
}
 
int16_t app_get_report_callback(uint8_t interface, uint8_t report_type, uint8_t report_id, const void **report, usb_ep0_data_stage_callback *callback, void **context) {
    /* This isn't a composite device, so there's no need to check the
     * interface here. Also, we know that there's only one report for
     * this device, so there's no need to check report_type or report_id.
     *
     * Set report, callback, and context; and the USB stack will send
     * the report, calling our callback (get_report_callback()) when
     * it has finished.
     */
    *report = report_buf;
    *callback = get_report_callback;
    *context = NULL;
 
    return sizeof(report_buf);
}
 
int8_t app_set_report_callback(uint8_t interface, uint8_t report_type, uint8_t report_id) {
    /* To handle Set_Report, call usb_start_receive_ep0_data_stage()
     * here. See the documentation for HID_SET_REPORT_CALLBACK() in
     * usb_hid.h. For this device though, there are no output or
     * feature reports. */
    return -1;
}
 
uint8_t app_get_idle_callback(uint8_t interface, uint8_t report_id) {
    return 0;
}
 
int8_t app_set_idle_callback(uint8_t interface, uint8_t report_id, uint8_t idle_rate) {
    return -1;
}
 
int8_t app_get_protocol_callback(uint8_t interface) {
    return 1;
}
 
int8_t app_set_protocol_callback(uint8_t interface, uint8_t report_id) {
    return -1;
}
 
 
#ifdef _PIC14E
    void interrupt isr() {
        usb_service();
    }
#elif _PIC18
    #ifdef __XC8
        void __interrupt(high_priority) isr() {
            usb_service();
        }
    #elif _PICC18
        #error need to make ISR
    #endif
#endif
```

I use XC8 (v2.31) compiler.

To clarify what is actually happening... When I upload a project to the device as presented here, I always get a different value, although I set the bit for "continuous conversion" in ADS, only one value is displayed at the time, which is (at least for me) some of the mysterious way more or less random, no matter how much I press the loadcell. I use the DIView program to display the values that my device sends to the PC. The device is defined as a game controller.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello! I could not understand your description of what is happening. Could you show an example of the output you get vs. the output you expect?

Comment: Do not double post see here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67640816/pic18f25k50-ads1114-and-i2c